# Nested List Comparison in Python

Tags: python-2.7, list-comparison

i have 2 lists.

```
list1 = [['vlan 158', '  name MARKE', '  mode vpc'], []]
list2 = [['vlan 158', '  name MARKETING', '  mode vpc'], ['vlan 159', '  name SALES', '  mode vpc']]
```

The first element of list has to be matched .If its matched then its fine.If not then expecting the diff as output.

Expected output :

```
+++++++++++++++++ The missing configuration is++++++++++++++

vlan 159
  name SALES
  mode vpc
+++++++++++++++++ The missing configuration is++++++++++++++
```

i am trying the below but not working:

```
print ("+++++++++++++++++ The missing configuration is++++++++++++++\n")
p = [item for index, item in enumerate(list2) if [] != [it for it in item if it not in list1[index]]]
print('\n'.join(['\n'.join(item) for item in p]))
print ("+++++++++++++++++ The missing configuration is++++++++++++++\n")
q = [item for index, item in enumerate(list1) if [] != [it for it in item if it not in list2[index]]]
print('\n'.join(['\n'.join(item) for item in q]))
```

Please suggest how it can be done ?

Current OutPut:

```
+++++++++++++++++ The missing configuration is++++++++++++++

vlan 158
  name MARKETING
  mode vpc
vlan 159
  name SALES
  mode vpc
+++++++++++++++++ The missing configuration is++++++++++++++

vlan 158
  name MARKE
  mode vpc
```

Comment: And what's wrong with the code you're trying?

Comment: its giving me the output mentioning "vlan 158 " also as there is "name" mismatch under that..i dont want that as " vlan 158" is available on both list..

Comment: How did you come up with your solution?

Comment: @MadPhysicist i am still looking for solution... my requirement is if the first element is matched then it should nt be shown as a difference in output..